How do i calculate the left and top position, when i scale a movabale image in a container?
i want to scale the image correctly,
but i dont know how to set the left position (x) and the top position (y)
here is my code in the template
<div id="container" :style="`height: ${height}px;width: ${size}px;overflow: hidden;position: relative;`">
   <img  @load="getSize()" id="bgPic" :src="`${bgPicture}`" :width="`${bgWidth}`"
            :height="`${bgHeight}`"
            :style="`cursor: ${cursor};left:${x}px; top:${y}px;display: block;position: relative;`"
            />
</div>

and in the scale function
event.preventDefault()
const scroll = event.deltaY * -0.001
const switching = Math.sign(scroll) 
this.cursor = switching == 1 ? 'zoom-in' : 'zoom-out'
this.bgHeight = parseFloat(this.bgHeight) + parseFloat(this.bgHeight) * scroll
this.bgWidth = parseFloat(this.bgWidth) + parseFloat(this.bgWidth) * scroll
this.x = ?
this.y = ?

i have come this far
 this.x = this.x / (1 + scroll) 
 this.y = this.y / (1 + scroll)

but there is still a small deviation

Reference this: CSS Change X position of text tag.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

thanks for your answer, but i can't use translate

You can try changing the top and left within the style.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

yes, but calculating the top and left values ​​is giving me problems, that's the point

you should not do calculations within in-line style.

Based on your post you would just access top with ‘this.style.top’

I access top with the y value and left with the x value: this.y and this.x
